# CakePHP searchable tags

Tags: php, cakephp, tags, e-commerce

I have made an online shop for clothes and probably I need to make some tagging system.

The whole application is build on CakePHP and I need an idea for managing all the products, something similar to ebay.

For example to tag each product with it's `price` , `type`, `producer`, `size` , `status`

And for example some of them should be multi-searchable, to be able to search for an item with: price between $10 and $20, with size S or M

Comment: None of those fields actually sound like tags to me, so much as fields already on the products table (or to be added), which are easily sortable using the pagination system.

Answer (score 0):

Have an attributes table that will basically act as a key/value storage and assign these attributes to each product.

Attributes itself could have an attribute_options table from where you can read the different available sizes for an attribute.

You'll then just have to search the attributes table and product table.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, you shouldn't need any additional tables.  Just add them as fields in the product table, and query based on that.  It will be faster, more logically laid out...etc.

Your example would be searchable like below.  (It seems a bit overkill, but will make any future finds really simple, and follows the fat controller, skinny model mantra:

```
//ProductsController
public function whatever() {
    $opts = array(
        'price_high' => 10,
        'price_low' => 20,
        'sizes' => array('S', 'M')
    );
    $this->Product->getProducts($opts);
}


//Product Model
public function getProduts($opts = null) {

    //initialize variables
    $params = array('conditions'=>array());

    //size(s)
    if(!empty($opts['sizes']) {
        array_push($params['conditions'], array('Product.size'=>$opts['sizes']));
    }

    //price(s)
    if(!empty($opts['price_high']) {
        array_push($params['conditions'], array('Product.price <='=>$opts['price_high']));
    }
    if(!empty($opts['price_low']) {
        array_push($params['conditions'], array('Product.price >='=>$opts['price_low']));
    }

    return $this->find('all', $params);
}
```